# How to optimize MySQL table containing 1.6+ million records for LIKE '%abc%' querying

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a table with this structure and it currently contains about 1.6 million records.

```
CREATE TABLE `chatindex` (
    `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `roomname` varchar(90) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `username` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `filecount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `connection` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `primaryip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `primaryport` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `rank` int(1) NOT NULL,
    `hashcode` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`,`roomname`,`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Both the roomname and username columns can contain the same exact data, but the uniqueness and the important bit of each item comes from combining the timestamp with those two items.

The query that is starting to take a while (10-20 seconds) is this:

```
SELECT timestamp,roomname,username,primaryip,primaryport 
    FROM `chatindex`
    WHERE username LIKE '%partialusername%'
```

What exactly can I do to optimize this? I can't do `partialusername%` because for some queries I will only have a small bit of the center of the actual username, and not the first few characters from the beginning of the actual value.

Edit:

Also, would sphinx be better for this particular purpose?

Comment: if you need "%part%" then you must do it. what will you use the result of the query for? can you change your approach on non-database side?

Answer (score 5):

Use [Fulltext indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql56-labs-july2011.html) , these are actually designed for this purpose. Now InnoDb support fulltext indexes in MySQL 5.6.4.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create Index on table column username (*full-text indexing*).
2. As an idea, you can create some views on this table that will contain filtered data on the basis of alphabets or other criteria and based on that your code will decide which view to use to fetch the search results.

Answer (score 2):

You should use MyISAM table to do `Fulltext` search as it supports FULLTEXT indexes, MySQL v5.6+ is still under development phase you should not use it as a production servers and it may take ~1 year to go GA.

Now, You should convert this table as MyISAM and add FULLTEXT index which refers `column` in where clause:

These links can be useful:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: what advantage does a fulltext index add over a normal index for this query.  Any index on `username` will prevent the full table scan.  This type of query will not make any use of the full text features.

Answer (score 1):

On MSSQL this is a perfect case to use fulltext indexes together with CONTAIN clause. The LIKE clause fails to obtain a good performance on such big table and with so many variants of text to search for.

Take a look onto this link, there are many issues related to [dinamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you do an explain on the current query, you will see that you are doing a full table scan of the table which is why it is so slow.  An index on username will materially speed up the search as the index can be cached by MySQL and the table row entries will only be accessed for matching users.

A fulltext index will *not* materially help searches like `%fred%` to match `oldfredboy` etc. so I am at loss as to why others are recommending using this.  What a fulltext index does is to create a wordlist based index so that list you search for something like "explain the current query" the fulltext engine does a intersect of row IDs containing "explain" with those containing "current" and those containing "query" to get a list of ID which contain all three.  Adding a fulltext index materially increases the insert , update on delete costs for the table, so it does add a performance penalty.   Furthermore, you need to use the fulltext-specific "MATCH" syntax to make full use of a fulltext index.

If you do a question search on "[mysql] fulltext like" to see further discussion on this.

A normal index will do everything that you need.  Searches like '%fred%' require a full scan of the index what ever you do so you need to keep the index as lean as possible.  Also if a high % of hits match 'fred%', then it might also be worth first trying a like 'fred%' search first as this will do an index range scan.

One other point, why are you using the **timestamp, roomname, username** as the primary key?  This doesn't make sense to me.  If you don't use the primary key as an access path then an auto_increment id is easier.  I would have thought **roomname, timestamp, username** would make some sense as you surely tend to access rooms within a time window.

Only add indexes that you will use.

Answer (score 0):

Table index(full text indexes) is must for such high volumes of data. 
Further if possible go for partitioning of table. so these will definitely improve the performance.